# String vs NSStringFromClass inside dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

Each of these call a different constructor.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(MessageSentDateCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageSentDateCell
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageSentDateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MessageSentDateCell
```

The top calls:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

The second line calls:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

However, in the sample project repository I'm referring to, `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is not really implemented. So I want to call the first constructor. Any ideas why the second line will not call the first constructor instead?

Yes, the class name and identifier are the same.

Comment: The appropriate technique depends upon how you're implementing your UI: Is it a storyboard cell prototype? A NIB? Or is the cell instantiated programmatically?

Comment: I am using a Storyboard cell prototype that conforms to the class I specified and programmed

Comment: And you hooked up all of your IBOutlets to properties of the cell subclass? Then your second `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` which will call `initWithCoder` is the appropriate method for the storyboard to call when instantiating the custom subclass. Put any custom initialization inside that `initWithCoder` method, or have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do the necessary additional configuration when `initWithCoder` is done. And if you don't need any special configuration (other than the outlets), then you simply don't need to implement `initWithCoder` at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your cell setup as a prototype cell in your storyboard, than the initCoder initializer is the initializer that should be called. This is because your cell has been encoded into the storyboard file and is being created by deserializing it. `initStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is for proramatically generated cells.

The reason that these two calls are producing different results is that NSStringFromClass is not returning "MessageSentDataCell" as you might expect. Swift classes are mangled to include their module name and other information so that you can have multiple of the same class exist in different modules.

Since the dequeue is not failing, you must be registering the MessageSentDateCell class with the tableview separate of the protocol using the same NSStringFromClass method.

You should choose to either load your cell programmatically and get rid of the prototype in the storyboard, or stick to the storyboard. If you have additional setup you have to do for the prototype cell, you should do it in the `awakeFromNib` method on your cell subclass because that will be called once all outlets are already connected.